# Does $|\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} f(N)|^2$ equal $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} |f(N)|^2$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Does
$$\left|\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} f(N)\right|^2 = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} |f(N)|^2, \tag{1}$$
where $f(N)$ is a function of $N$ and $N$ is a natural number?

Here is my try: $y(x)=|x|^2$ is a continuous function of $x$, so (1) is true. Am I right?

Comment: The question, as it currently stands, is a little ambiguous.  It is entirely possible for the RHS to exist even though the LHS does not.  So it would not be fair to call the two sides equal without any qualifiers.  On the other hand, if the LHS exists, then yes it is equal to the RHS because $|x|^2$ is continuous.

Comment: Understand! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{C}$ by
$$
f(n)=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{$n$ is odd}\\
-1,&\text{$n$ is even}
\end{cases}.
$$
Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}|f(n)|^2=1$, but $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)$ does not exist and $\left|\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)\right|^2$ does not, either. If $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)$ exists, then the equation holds.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If $f(N) \to A$ as $ N \to \infty$, then $|f(N)| \to |A|$ and thus $|f(N)|^2 \to |A|^2$.